# SMS Apps as Front-end to Google Voice

Tags: sms, google-voice

Suppose I use Google Voice for text messaging rather than my carrier's SMS plan. Would it be possible to use SMS Apps such as Handcent etc. as the interface or front-end to GV's text messages?

Comment: I don't know of a way currently, but I would be highly interested in a solution for this! +1!!